# How to copy a codepen.io example into a .vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, codepen

I found a codepen.io example (https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm) I want to play around with in the context of a .vue app I'm working on, and I need some help transferring the `<script>` section over.

I copied the HTML chunk into a `<template>` and the CSS into a `<style>`.  I've confirmed the .vue file works within the broader context (content loads when the `<script>` is commented out.  I also placed `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" />` immediately before my `<script>` to resolve the `$ not defined` error I was getting.  Is there something I need to import into App.vue or into this particular .vue file?  When I leave `<script>` uncommented, I simply get a blank page loaded.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" />
<script>
var hidWidth;
var scrollBarWidths = 40;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could define a method like this:

```
methods: {
     renderStuff: function () {
       var hidWidth;
       var scrollBarWidths = 40;

       var widthOfList = function(){
       var itemsWidth = 0;
       $('.list li').each(function(){
       var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
       itemsWidth+=itemWidth;
    });
  return itemsWidth;
};

  var widthOfHidden = function(){
    return (($('.wrapper').outerWidth())-widthOfList()-getLeftPosi())- 
    scrollBarWidths;
   };

var getLeftPosi = function(){
  return $('.list').position().left;
};

var reAdjust = function(){
  if (($('.wrapper').outerWidth()) < widthOfList()) {
    $('.scroller-right').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.scroller-right').hide();
  }

  if (getLeftPosi()<0) {
    $('.scroller-left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.item').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow');
    $('.scroller-left').hide();
  }
}

reAdjust();

$(window).on('resize',function(e){  
    reAdjust();
});

$('.scroller-right').click(function() {

  $('.scroller-left').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-right').fadeOut('slow');

  $('.list').animate({left:"+="+widthOfHidden()+"px"},'slow',function(){

  });
});

$('.scroller-left').click(function() {

    $('.scroller-right').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.scroller-left').fadeOut('slow');

    $('.list').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow',function(){

    });
});    
   }
}
```

and run the method on mount like this:

```
mounted() {
   this.renderStuff();
}
```

Side note, var is not ideal in this day and age. Recommend converting these to `let`.

Comment: Thanks!  This resolves the content not loading issue, however, it does not demonstrate the same functionality as the codepen.io example.  Is there another adjustment I need to make to get the JS functional?  
`<script>  
export default {  
  mounted() {  
    this.renderStuff();  
  },  
  methods: {  
  renderStuff: function() {  
  var hidWidth;
  var scrollBarWidths = 40;`

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console when the page loads?

Comment: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"  And thanks for the direction there - once it stopped getting caught by VSCode, I didn't think to check to see if I still had the error in console.

Comment: Yes, always check the console when things go amiss. Sounds like vue is having a hard time working with jQuery with your current configuration. There may be a Vue-specific way to register the jQuery library, but I'm not familiar with that config. If you wanted to you could do the references with vanilla JS or with Vue $refs, and ditch jQuery entirely.